# Все inline-block justify, но последняя строка center (css)

Tags: html, css

Есть неограниченное количество блоков (пусть будет шесть) с text-align и text-align-last: justify.
[image: начальное положение]

Уменьшаем область просмотра, они все еще justify, все хорошо.
[image: небольшое уменьшение]

В какой-то момент последний блок переносится на новую строку и прилипает к левой части.
[image: поведение по умолчанию]

Тогда как хотелось бы, чтобы он был по центру.
[image: желаемый результат]

Реализация при помощи JS:

[Демо](https://jsfiddle.net/srruk1Lt/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{margin:0;padding:0;}

.wrapper{
    background: pink;
    font-size: 0;
}

.child{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: gray;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

    .center{
        text-align: justify;
        text-align-last: center;
    }

    .justify{
        text-align: justify;
        text-align-last: justify;
    }
```

JS:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

var firstChild = wrapper.firstElementChild;
firstChild.oldTop = firstChild.offsetTop;

var lastChild = wrapper.lastElementChild;
lastChild.oldTop = lastChild.offsetTop;

if(lastChild.oldTop !== firstChild.oldTop)
    wrapper.classList.add('center');
else
    wrapper.classList.add('justify');

window.onresize = function()
{
    if(firstChild.oldTop !== lastChild.offsetTop)
    {
        wrapper.classList.remove('justify');
        wrapper.classList.add('center');
    }
    else
    {
        wrapper.classList.remove('center');
        wrapper.classList.add('justify');
    }
};
```

**Вопрос:** Можно ли сделать тоже самое без js ?

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```css
html, body{margin:0;padding:0;}

.wrapper{
  background: pink;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.child{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, у вас изначально все блоки выровнены по центру родителя, тогда как они должны быть выровнены по ширине

Comment: У вас написано "но при уменьшении области просмотра и переносе последнего/предпоследнего и тд последняя строка была бы text-aligh: center."  Что такое "последнего/предпоследнего и тд"? Чем ограничивается "тд"? У меня "тд" дошло до всех элементов. Пишите вопрос тогда четче.

Comment: Переформулировал вопрос, извиняюсь за плохое описание

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем то, но может быть, вам подойдет?

```css
html, body{margin:0;padding:0;}

.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  background: pink;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child{
 
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```